# SAPUI5 - oModel.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, abap

I'm trying to build a simple SAPUI5 application that basically lists a table filled with employee data (ID, name, address). 
[image]

However, I cannot add new employee because I always get the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: oModel.create is not a function
>       at constructor.Save (EmpDetails.controller.js?eval:87)

Could you please help me solve this? I don't understand why the create function does not work given that it is connected to the model and should work fine (just like the GET-method that fills the table on initialization).
Here is my code for the controller:

```js
sap.ui.controller("zemployee_crud.EmpDetails", {

 onInit: function() {
  var sServiceUrl = "proxy/http/<server>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZEMPLOYEE_SRV";
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);

  var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

  oModel.read("/EmployeeSet",null,null,true,function(oData,response){
   oJsonModel.setData(oData);
  });

  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oJsonModel);
 },

 Save: function() {
  var oId = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Id").getValue();
  var oName = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Name").getValue();
  var oAddress = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Address").getValue(); 
  
  var oEntry = {};

  oEntry.Empid = oId;
  oEntry.Empname = oName;
  oEntry.Empadd = oAddress;
  
  var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
  
  oModel.create("/EmployeeSet", oEntry, null, function (response) {
   // success message
   // table reload
  }, function (Error) {
   //show error 
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSONModel does not support `create`. You have to use an ODataModel.

First you have to store your model somewhere

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

Then later you can access the model and call create.

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
oModel.create(...);
```

---

This is the most simple approach. I strongly suggest getting to know the framework:

- `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` is deprecated. Use `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`.
- Declare your model in your manifest.json. Then all controllers can access it.
- In most cases you don't need an extra JSONModel. You can directly use the ODataModel and show it in your list
- Setting any model (JSON or OData) to the core (`sap.ui.getCore().setModel()`) is not necessary. The core is on a very high/global level. Mostly it's enough to set it on an app/component level (either in your manifest.json or in the Component.js) or on a controller level.

I also strongly suggest doing the [official walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db). It takes 1-2 days to complete but after that you are almost a pro since it answers 95% of all beginner questions.